# Updating record number after deletion in asp.net MVC 4 razor view

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on asp.net MVC 4 application. I have created a list using foreach loop and declared a variable to show record number. Each row has a delete icon, which when clicked, deletes that record and hides that row. this works fine except one issue. When user deletes first record or any record in middle of list, I want the record number of all the rows to be updated accordinlgy.

Here is razor view code:

```
  @{ 

   int i = 1;
   foreach (var item in cartItem.CartItemsByStore)
   {
    <tr id="cartrow-@item.CartItemID">
        <td class="transaction">@i</td>
        <td class="item-details">
            <img src="/images/tmp/order-product.jpg" width="63" height="63">
            <div class="desc">
                <span>
                    <p>@item.ItemName</p>


                </span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="date-time">15 Jun 2014</td>
        <td class="action">
            <a href="#" data-id="@item.CartItemID" class="removeCartItem delete" title="Delete">X</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sp" id="sp-@item.CartItemID">
        <td colspan="20"></td>
    </tr>
    i++;
   }
  }
```

and here is deletion code:

```
$(function () {
        // Document.ready -> link up remove event handler
        $(".removeCartItem").click(function () {
            if (confirm("Click OK if you want to delete this record; otherwise, click 'Cancel'")) {
                // Get the id from the link
                var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");
                if (recordToDelete != '') {
                    // Perform the ajax post
                    $.post("/Cart/DeleteCartItem", { "id": recordToDelete },
                        function (data) {
                            // Successful requests get here
                            $('#cartrow-' + recordToDelete).fadeOut('hide');
                            $('#sp-' + recordToDelete).fadeOut('hide');
                            $('#spCartCount').text(data);
                            $('#row-' + recordToDelete).fadeOut('hide');
                        });
                }
            }
        });

 });
```

Comment: you are using i to display the row id, so when you will delete top or any middle entry then u need to reload the complete loop.

Best way I can suggest is to use Partial View for it

Comment: As @Geek said, have a strongly typed partial view with "CartItemsByStore" as model and refresh partial view after every deletion

Comment: How to refresh the partial view if i put all this html in a new partial view

Comment: Put partialview in some div and return partialview from "DeleteCartItem" action method.

Comment: Can you send me some sample code to return partialview from deletecartitem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Partial view : "Store.csthml"

```
@model IEnumerable<CartItemsByStore>

@{ 

   int i = 1;
   foreach (var item in Model)
   {
    <tr id="cartrow-@item.CartItemID">
        <td class="transaction">@i</td>
        <td class="item-details">
            <img src="/images/tmp/order-product.jpg" width="63" height="63">
            <div class="desc">
                <span>
                    <p>@item.ItemName</p>


                </span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="date-time">15 Jun 2014</td>
        <td class="action">
            <a href="#" data-id="@item.CartItemID" class="removeCartItem delete" title="Delete">X</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sp" id="sp-@item.CartItemID">
        <td colspan="20"></td>
    </tr>
    i++;
   }
  }
```

CartController:

```
public ActionResult ReturnView()
{
    //populate model
    IEnumerable<CartItemsByStore>model =db.GetItemsByStore();
    return PartialView("Store",model)
}

public ActionResult DeleteCartItem(int id)
{
    //delete
   return RedirectToAction("ReturnView");
}
```

Main View:

```
<div id="divStore">
@Html.Partial("Store",cartItem.CartItemsByStore)
</div>

$(".removeCartItem").click(function () {
            if (confirm("Click OK if you want to delete this record; otherwise, click 'Cancel'")) {
                // Get the id from the link
                var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");
                if (recordToDelete != '') {
                    // Perform the ajax post
                    $.post("/Cart/DeleteCartItem", { "id": recordToDelete },
                        function (data) {
                            // Successful requests get here
                            $("#divStore").html(data);
                        });
                }
            }
        });
```